# Swift: How to let background thread wait for user input?

Tags: swift

I have a background thread which needs some user input. Since it is not recommended to call an NSAlert window from a background thread, I like to do this in the main thread. But how can I let the background thread wait till the NSAlert window is closed?

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // some background task

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // UI task asking for user input:
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "Some text"
        alert.informativeText = "Some information"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Yes")
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("No")
        result = alert.runModal()
    }

    // some background task, treating user input (Yes/No)
}
```

Comment: You should never "wait" in Cocoa programming.

Comment: Could you break your work into two sections: before user input and after user input (separate methods, blocks, etc.)? Then after you get the user input, kick off the "after user input" section, passing whatever data you need, by sending it to the background queue? That way you don't need to block the queue waiting.

Comment: Exactly what Matt says: You _never_ wait. You spin off a task, like you did, and supply it with callbacks that get executed when the task finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `runModal` method is synchronous. If you want to wait for it to finish, rather than dispatching asynchronously to the main queue with `dispatch_async`, you can most easily achieve what you asked for by dispatching it synchronously with `dispatch_sync`, e.g.:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue) {
    // some background task

    var result: NSModalResponse!

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {     // note, `dispatch_sync`
        // UI task asking for user input:
        let alert = NSAlert()
        ...
        result = alert.runModal()
    }

    // some background task, treating user input (Yes/No)
}
```

---

A more subtle problem rests with the synchronous nature `runModal`. This will block the main thread. This is not generally a good idea. It can interfere with other tasks your app might be performing (timers, animations, network operations using the main queue, etc.) that might require the main thread.

So, instead of the synchronous `runModal`, you might consider presenting the `NSAlert` asynchronously with `beginSheetModalForWindow`, with a completion handler that dispatches additional background processing to the background queue, e.g.:

```
let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(queue) {
    // some background task

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {   // note, `dispatch_async` is OK here
        // UI task asking for user input:
        let alert = NSAlert()
        ...
        alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(NSApp.mainWindow!) { result in
            dispatch_async(queue) {
                // some background task, treating user input (Yes/No)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This achieves what you want (triggering additional background tasks when the modal is dismissed), but has the virtue of not blocking the main thread at all.

Answer (score -2):

You can use semaphore.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    // some background task

    //Create a semaphore with count = 0
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // UI task asking for user input:
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "Some text"
        alert.informativeText = "Some information"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Yes")
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("No")
        result = alert.runModal()
        //Signal semaphore
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }

    //Wait for semaphore
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
    // some background task, treating user input (Yes/No)
}
```

You should not "wait" **in the main thread**. But background threads are other things.

Comment: Yes, waiting on background thread is not as serious of a problem as waiting on the main thread, but it's still a practice to be discouraged as it's an inefficient use of resources. In this case, you're consuming one of the limited number of worker threads available to the global queue.

Comment: @Rob Yes, it may cause a problem, if you are already using nearly the limit of worker threads. By the way, how many is the limit number in OS X/macOS? In case the cost of invoking threads is not ignorable, invoking threads frequently should be avoided. Case by case. You should not say "Always avoid waiting", but say "Always check if this case fits for waiting".

Comment: First, while there is some cost to starting up threads, that's one of the reasons why we use GCD, to avail ourselves of a pool of work threads rather than spinning one up ourselves. Second, I agree that you shouldn't categorically say "never wait",  but you should only do so when it's absolutely needed (and it's not needed here). Third, you've actually taken code that blocked the main thread (by calling `runModal`) and made it worse. You now block the main thread _and_ one of the worker threads.

Comment: @Rob I have read YOUR opinion and I don't mind you express your opinions where you can. But I recommend you to reconsider, in what cases occupying one thread would be so harmful.

Comment: I mean no offense: I agree that those cases exist (though I contend that they're rare, but we can respectfully disagree on that point). The more important observation, though, is that this certainly is not one of those cases. The OP presented code that blocked the main thread and this code here just blocks a background thread, waiting for code that still blocks the main thread. Not only does this not solve the original problem, but it blocks yet another thread for no reason. The pattern you suggest can be used when trying to wait for an asynchronous task, but `runModal` is synchronous.

Comment: Sorry, it was in the morning when I wrote the last comment, and I had not enough time to express all my feelings. I really appreciate that you have said 'I agree that you shouldn't categorically say "never wait"' and also that you have reminded me that `runModal` thing. I believe we can find many points to agree, (some needs ongoing discussion, though). As I said, I would express my opinion where I could. And as you see in your own answer, readers can express their opinions as well.